# Question on Debug Logs panel in Developer Console?

Tags: apex, debugging

1)Why there are two rows in the Change Log Levels window in the Developer Console? with different expiration times, one in red color and one in green color?

[image]

2) Even when I set all the log levels to ERROR and set the expiration time to 2 hours in future, the log levels change to INFO and DEBUG with expiration time to current time after I run a test class which I am trying to debug. Why is it so?  Which row should I update?

Answer (score 2):

Note that one is specific to General Trace settings to Users (the upper ones) while the lower is specific to overrides to your default settings for Class and Trigger Debug settings. So the upper two would be for when you're trying to follow a User's debug logs (up to two) that's you've set for 20 debug traces in Setup.

The other would be for your specific testing of Classes or Triggers that you're doing in the Dev Console. If you want to update one of them temporarily for your testing of a class or trigger in the console, you'll want to do it below using the Add button. You can add those classes and they'll appear down below as shown in this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: But when I change the log levels for the second row in the screenshot, the log levels and everything are reset back and It does no have any effect on my debug logs.

Comment: Apologies, let me be a bit more specific. The upper two that you're showing are for TWO specific users. You can have two different specific users with two different expiration times. The overrides below are for specific classes or triggers that you add and specify the overrides for. Is that clearer for you?

Comment: How do I figure out who is the other user that second row corresponds to? The changes I make to the first row are persisting but the changes to the second row are erased and no effect on the logs.

Comment: It applies when a second user is configured to be using debug logs from the Dev Console at the same time you are. Are you in a dev org or production org?